# Will a frozen up Evaporator Coil in a heat pump cause the Air Handler Fan Motor to die?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump

My previous question was closed, saying it was opinion based, but it was not, so I'll ask again.

The fan motor in our air handler died and was replaced by an HVAC tech.  That lasted 1 day, then the evap coil froze up.

The tech first said that the problem was that the new motor was defective and spinning backwards, so they ordered another.

After installing the second motor, the tech said that the evap coil freezing up caused the new motor to die, that there is a freon leak and it will keep killing fan motors every time it freezes up.

Everything I've read says that freezing up triggers the safety system and shuts down the air handler fan motor, but that it will work again once it thaws. I read this on here in an answer to other questions, as well on 2 other sites.

So I'll clarify my question here...

Can the evap coil freezing up KILL the air handler fan motor?

Or is there perhaps something else killing the air handler fan motors?

Also, not looking for opinion here,  but facts...

What is the typical price to replace a Genteq fan motor model 5SBA39GLV5154?

I realize prices vary based on location, but I am looking for info from actual HVAC techs as to what they would charge to replace said motor - parts and labor.

Not to be a D, but I am not interested in the opinion of a random person who does not do HVAC work.  Because you gave your opinion on my last question, does not mean I was asking for your opinion.  I'm looking for facts here, so PLEASE don't feel obligated to give your opinion just to boost your score on here and shut down my question because all you had to offer was your opinion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The people that vote to close your question arent necessarily the ones that are answering it.  There are a still a few issues. First there are too many questions, we need one question each time. Second, please read the help  **The cost of a job or the price of tools as these will vary between locations and over time.** And dont shoot the messenger!

Comment: If a question is closed for opinion, the proper course is to use the edit button right below the keywords, to [edit] the question so it is correct and nominate for re-opening.  Doing so bumps it to the top of the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the help/suggestions. I don't intend to make a career out of using this forum, and can't devote 20hrs to reading/memorizing all the rules, then rewriting my question to appease the die hard forum trolls vying for the most points.

Comment: Well, this "Karen" act you're pulling here, I'm sure you didn't treat the HVAC techs any better than us, did not listen to a word they said, did not understand the work done and billed for. "$3000 for a blower replacement" - I'm more inclined to believe there was a lot of other work done you're not mentioning, and you are misleading us because it's a more righteous narraitve for social media.  GIGO: we can't give accurate answers on inaccurate info, and it wouldn't be appreciated anyway. *eyeroll* I advise steering clear of this asker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an evaporator coil freezes this means its surface is literally covered with ice -- frozen water. As ice begins to form it starts blocking air flow through the coil. The reduced air flow leads to the coil growing colder, which leads to ice forming faster, and air flow further reduced. It's somewhat like the cascading of an avalanche.

The blower motor's job is to push air through the evaporator. The job becomes increasingly difficult as the evaporator ices over. The motor works harder, causing it to generate more heat than usual.

But how is that blower motor cooled? *By the flow of air through the air handler.* So yes, the reduced volume of air passing through a frozen evap coil leads to an overheating blower motor. Many systems do not have a freeze detection sensor; the only thing that may protect the motor from overheat damage is its built-in thermal protector. The thermal protection might be auto-resetting so that the motor will begin running again when it has cooled a bit. *There's no guarantee that the evaporator will have cleared by the time the motor re-starts, though -- in fact it's likely the evaporator will still be blocked.*

A motor "should" survive a single overheat event with relatively minor damage. Repeated overheat, though, will almost certainly cause failure in short order. This could easily have happened to yours.

Incidentally.. in my own life a frozen coil led to a burned up motor, which led to replacing my home's 27-year old HVAC equipment with new stuff, and then to my getting into the HVAC industry. :-)

I can't help you with the pricing part of the question -- because the DIY site serves a global audience, and pricing varies regionally, nationally, and across time, "what's the typical cost of ___" is specifically off-topic. You're on the right track to be looking for the retail-to-you cost of a part and estimating the hourly rate you might pay for comparable skilled trades in your area.

Comment: Thanks Greg, much appreciated!

Comment: yeah, and an R22 unit is probably using bang-bang controls, R G Y and all that, which provide no means for the compressor to know the evaporator is iced.